# CSS: Smooth transition between hover and leaving

Tags: html, css

This is my html code:

```css
li.searchbar a.searchbar-text:hover {
  color: red !important;
  margin-left: -10px;
  transition: opacity .9s, margin-left .5s, margin-right .5s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .9s, margin-left .5s, margin-right .5s;
}
```

```html
<li class="col-sm-5 searchbar">
  <a class="text-left"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a class="searchbar-text">
    <span class="first-seach-text">Search France</span>
    <span class="second-seach-text">and beyond</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

With mouse hover, it moves to left smoothly, but when the mouse leaves, it moves back to right fast.(I expect smoothly).

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8kW7y/15/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transition on hover will not affect the normal state

```css
li.searchbar a.searchbar-text{
 transition: opacity .9s, margin-left .5s, margin-right .5s;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .9s, margin-left .5s, margin-right .5s;
}
li.searchbar a.searchbar-text:hover {
 color: red !important;
 margin-left:-10px;
}
```

```html
            <li class="col-sm-5 searchbar"><a class="text-left"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a class="searchbar-text"><span class="first-seach-text">Search France</span><span class="second-seach-text">and beyond</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 6):

So the transition takes place on the hover but not on the off. So you need to set the transition on the element without the hover state.

for example: for your demo add

```
li.searchbar a.searchbar-text {
  transition:all .5s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the transition settings have to be in the CSS for the normal state. Second, for each to-be-transitioned property you need settings in *both*  rules between which the transition should be made. And third, transitions for which there is not setting (opacity and margin-right in your case) have no effect.

```css
li.searchbar a.searchbar-text {
    color: initial;
    margin-left: 0px;
    transition: color .9s, margin-left .5s;
    -webkit-transition: color .9s, margin-left .5s;
}
li.searchbar a.searchbar-text:hover {
    color: red;
    margin-left:-10px;
}
```

```html
    <li class="col-sm-5 searchbar">
       <a class="text-left"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       <a class="searchbar-text">
         <span class="first-seach-text">Search France</span>
         <span class="second-seach-text">and beyond</span>
       </a>
   </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy fix is to simply add the same transition to the original element (as well as the hover state of the element).

```css
.effect {
border: none;
margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.effect:hover {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
-moz-transform: scale(1.1);
-o-transform: scale(1.1);
transform: scale(1.1);
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Johannes said add the transition effect on the rule element and not on the hover state and in the hover state you need to be specific on the desire effects; if you want margint-right and opacity you need to specify the rule for those effects:

```
li.searchbar a.searchbar-text {
  transition: color .9s, opacity .9s, margin-left .5s, margin-right .5s;
}

li.searchbar a.searchbar-text:hover {
  color: red;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

In this way the transition will be implemented when the cursor hover-over the element and when the cursor goes away.